# RStudio on Windows doesn't detect Git installation

Tags: windows, git, rstudio

I have followed the instructions as per "[Version Control with Git and SNV](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN)" but I do not get any possibility to select git for version control for my project in the Project settings.

I am on:

- Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
- RStudio: Version 0.99.902
- R: version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"

I have installed git 2.9.0 for Windows from https://git-scm.com/downloads.
It installs under `C:\Users\spi\AppData\Local\Programs\Git` (let's call it `gitroot`)

In RStudio and in `PATH` I tried (one at the time and closing/reopening RStudio every time) to specify all possible combinations of

`PATH` - `RStudio global settings`

as follows:

- `gitroot\cmd`   -  `gitroot\cmd\git.exe`
- `gitroot` - `gitroot\git-bash.exe`
- `gitroot` - `gitroot\git-cmd.exe`
- `gitroot` - `gitroot\mingw64\bin\git.exe`

Any hints is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If git was installed before RStudio, you wouldn't neet to set anything. RStudio would detect it although I noticed the path on my RStudio uses `/` instead of `\ `. I am able to use Git without issues. Try replacing `\ ` with `/`

Comment: Also make sure that git actually exists in the paths you tried. In my case, it's installed in `C:\Program Files\Git\Bin`. There is nothing in the path you provided and it's the *wrong* path to store application data anyway (much less executables). Each application is expected to create its own folder under `Local` directly

Comment: I can use `git` from the command line, both in `bash` and `cmd` flavor of the shell, i.e. invoking "Git Bash" or "Git CMD" from the Start menu.
I can also open a MS Windows `CMD` session and typing `where git` I git the right location, as well `git --version` works.
This is becoming puzzling...

Comment: The solution was to install Git for Windows in `C:\opt\Git` which looks like not to be a *special* folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install Git for Windows in `C:\opt\Git` which looks like not to be a *special* folder.

I was able to choose where to insall only after aborting a reinstallation.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the folder is, as long as you have access to it. There's nothing wrong with special folders for *your* account, ie, if your account is `spi` there is no real problem accessing anything installed in `ProgramData`. In fact, that's where package managers like chocolatey store packages. How did you install `Git` and how many different `git` packages did you install? SourceTreee, Github for Windows, the standalone Git, TortoiseGit all install their own copy of the binaries, or use an existing one.

Comment: PS you *should* have used `Program Files`, *not* a top-level folder like `opt`. Files in `Program Files` require administrative priviledges (similar to su) to prevent malware and viruses from modifying application files. `ProgramData` exists so that applications can write data without requiring extra priviledges

Comment: I do not have admin rights so I had to choose a decent folder. The solution I posted works while for some reason accessing `ProgramData` installations does not in my case...Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: What you posted is the same as installing anywhere else. Installing in `ProgramData` is a bad idea. It's simply the folder where applications store their data. Besides, where was RStudio installed in the first place? Another folder outside "Program Files"?

Comment: It was installed in C:/opt

Comment: That's why you can find git now. It's in the *same* folder as RStudio. You could install it in any other location and add it to the PATH variable - something that is done by the Git installer itself.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the path file from git-bash to gitcmd:

Correct Path file:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```